# Verilog operation unexpected result

Tags: verilog

I am studying verilog language and faced problems.

```
integer intA;
...
intA = - 4'd12 / 3; // expression result is 1431655761.
                    // -4’d12 is effectively a 32-bit reg data type
```

This snippet from standard and it blew our minds. The standard says that **4d12** - is a 4 bit number **1100**. 
Then **-4d12** = **0100**. It's okay now.

To perform the division, we need to bring the number to the same size. 4 to 32 bit. The number of bits **-4'd12** - is unsigned, then it should be equal to **32'b0000...0100**, but it equal to **32'b1111...10100**. Not ok, but next step.

My version of division: **-4d12 / 3** = **32'b0000...0100 / 32'b0000...0011** = **1**

Standart version: - **4'd12 / 3** = **1431655761**

Can anyone tell why? Why 4 bit number keeps extra bits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read section *11.8.2 Steps for evaluating an expression* of the 1800-2012 LRM. They key piece you are missing is that the operand is `4'd12` and that it is sized to 32 bits as an unsigned value before the unary `-` operator is applied.

If you want the 4-bit value treated as a signed -3, then you need to write

```
intA = - 4'sd12 / 3 // result is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

here the parser interprets -'d12 as 32 bits number which is unsigned initially and the negative sign would result in the negation of bits. so the result would be

negation of ('d12)= negation of (28 zeros + 1100)= 28ones+2zeros+2ones =
11111111111111111111111111110011. gives output to 4294967283 . if you divide this number (4294967283) by 3 the answer would be 1,431,655,761.

keep smiling :)